# Javascript not working as expected to work in Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hello every one I have small javascript for creating css popup window. This script is working very good in HTML but when I implemented this script in asp.net project it is not working as desired. The main function of this script is to open a css popup window for login field and remains on page until user close it. This function is working as usual in HTML page, but in asp.net master page it opens popup and close it automatically after 2 or 3 seconds. So please help me.
here is my code

MasterPage

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("Scripts/csspopup.js")%>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='s<%= ResolveUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")%>'></script>

<body>
<form id="TopForm" runat="server">
    <div id="topPanel">
        <div id="RegLoginPanel">
            <asp:Button ID="btn1" CssClass="btnLoginReg" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClientClick="popup('popUpDiv')" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btnLoginReg" Text="Register" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="blanket" style="display:none;">
        <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
            <a id="closeLogin" href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">X</a>
            <div id="DIVformLogin"><div class="formLogin">
                <input class="formLogin" type="text" />
                <input class="formLogin" type="text" /><br/>
                <input type="checkbox" class="RememberME"/><label>Keep me Sign In</label>
                <button class="btnSignIN" name="Login">Login</button><br/>
                <asp:Label CssClass="passForget" runat="server" ID="lblForget" Text="Forget Password"></asp:Label>
            </div></div>
        </div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
 function toggle(div_id) {
var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
if (el.style.display == 'none') { el.style.display = 'block'; }
else { el.style.display = 'none'; }
 }
function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
} else {
    viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
    blanket_height = viewportheight;
} else {
    if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
        blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
    } else {
        blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
    }
}
var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
popUpDiv_height = blanket_height / 2 - 150;///150 is half popup's height
popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
 }
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
} else {
    viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
    window_width = viewportwidth;
} else {
    if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
        window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
    } else {
        window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
    }
}
var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
window_width = window_width / 2 - 150;///*150 is half popup's width
popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
//  popUpDiv.style.left = 50 + 'px' ;
}
  function popup(windowname) {
blanket_size(windowname);
window_pos(windowname);
toggle('blanket');
toggle(windowname);
}
```

Comment: view the final markup using `view page source` or whatever the browser specific option is.. make sure you don't have the script files on the page more than once

Comment: I had done this before but it doesn't show any thing useful any suggestion regarding code above

Comment: Please include the javascript in the question it self as this is the most important part. Further , and this is unrelated to your problem, but apart from referencing the jQuery library, I'm not seeing much jQuery in your code. It is all plain javascript.

Comment: it sounds like you're calling the `function toggle(div_id) {` twice.. it just seems like you have to be calling `function popup(windowname)` more than once and usually that is because it's on the page more than once.. shouldnt take 2 seconds though so im not real sure

Comment: @JamieD77 I had reviewed your suggestion but the function is used once only, and also this code is forking fine in HTML and php.

Comment: You have referred `csspopup.js` before referring `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` library. Make it upside down and try!

Comment: @JonP Here is the javascript I used